# Can someone help me how to add fields in different table using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addreturnitem
AS
    UPDATE item_inventory
    SET Stocks = (Stocks + Quantity) 
    FROM item_inventory 
    INNER JOIN Item_return ON item_inventory.Item_id = Item_return.Item_id
```

Comment: Why do you need to join the table at all?

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: microsoft sql server  ..

Comment: sorry for not adding dbms im newbee in this page /.

Comment: Is this SP supposed to count some totals or operate with some specific `item_return`?

Comment: yes ivan , that sp opperate to add the item that have been borrow into item inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are running this query in Oracle DB.
The problem with your query is JOIN condition in UPDATE clause.
Oracle does not allow JOIN clause in Update statement.

You can edit your query like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addreturnitem
AS
UPDATE item_inventory inv 
   SET stocks = (SELECT inv.stocks + ret.quantity
                   FROM Item_return ret
                  WHERE ret.item_id = inv.item_id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM item_return ret2 
               WHERE ret2.item_id = inv.item_id);
```

Also, query can be edited like below which is more readable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addreturnitem
AS
UPDATE 
(SELECT inv.stock as stock, ret.quantity as ret_quantity
   FROM item_inventory inv
  INNER JOIN item_return ret
     ON inv.item_id = ret.item_id
) upd
SET upd.stock = upd.stock + upd.ret_quantity;
```

Comment: compare your query with op's query

Comment: can u pls elaborate ?

Comment: i said it would be good if you share what is the problem in op's query and why your solution would work rather his query

Comment: added explanation in my answer

Comment: how you know this is oracle db?

Comment: but this is valid sql for mssql server

Comment: mssql server sir . sorry for not adding dbms name .